# Is this a criterion for uniform distribution modulo one?

Tags: real-analysis, equidistribution

For all $k \in \mathbb N$ let $a_k$ be strictly positive bounded weights, i.e. there are constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $0<C_1\le a_k \le C_2$. Now a real valued sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ satisfies $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k)^m e^{2\pi i x_km}=0$ for all non-zero integers $m$. Does this imply that the sequence $x_k$ is uniformly distributed modulo one?

It is similar to the Weyl criterion and would surely not be true if we consider just weights $a_k$ where the condition would only imply weighted uniform distribution modulo one. But with the weights $(a_k)^m$ depending on the parameter $m$ this could be true.

Any thoughts or potential counterexamples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the "for all" applies to the "strictly positive bounded weights $a_k$," then in particular you can take $a_k=1$ for all $k$ and just recover Weyl. So maybe you mean "there exist strictly positive bounded weights $a_k$"?

Comment: Yes, the "for all" applies only to the integers m, so I added "there exist" to be clear, thx.

Comment: The quantifier on $a_k$ should come before they are used. Can you restate more carefully?

Comment: Thx, I restated and tried to be clearer on the weights $a_k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I provide a sequence $(x_k)_k$ that is not uniformly distributed but satisfies $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k \le N} a_k^m e^{2\pi i x_k m} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ for each $m \ge 1$, where $a_k = 1$ if $k$ is odd and $a_k = 3$ if $k$ is even. Let $x_k = 0$ if $k$ is odd. Then, for any $m \ge 1$, $\sum_{\substack{k \le N \\ 2 \nmid k}} e^{2\pi i x_k m} = \frac{1}{2}N+o(N)$, so it suffices to have, for any $m \ge 1$, $\sum_{\substack{k \le N \\ 2 \mid k}} e^{2\pi i x_k m} = \frac{-1}{2\cdot 3^m}N+o(N)$.

Rescaling, our general problem is to find a sequence $(x_k)_k$ such that $$\sum_{k \le N} e^{2\pi i x_k m} = \frac{-1}{3^m}N+o(N)$$ for each $m \ge 1$. I feel like there's a reference that guarantees this result, but let me say what I came up with (which has probably already been done somewhere). Let $f : \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{C}$ be such that $\hat{f}(0) = 1$, $\hat{f}(m) = -\frac{1}{3^m}$ for $m \ge 1$, and $\hat{f}(m) = \overline{\hat{f}(-m)}$ for $m \le -1$. Since the fourier coefficients decay rapidly, $f$ is continuous. Also, $f$ is real, due to how the negative fourier coefficients are defined. In fact, $f(x) = 1-2\sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{1}{3^m}\sin(2\pi m x)$, which in particular shows $f$ is non-negative. Therefore, for each $N \ge 1$, we may take rational approximations $\frac{j_0}{M_N},\dots,\frac{j_{N-1}}{M_N}$ to $f(\frac{0}{N}),f(\frac{1}{N}),\dots,f(\frac{N-1}{N})$ with $j_i \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ for each $i$. Let $s_N$ denote a block of length $T_N := j_0+\dots+j_{N-1}$ that has $\frac{t}{N}$ appearing $j_t$ times. Define our sequence $(x_k)_k$ by $2^{2^1+T_1}$ consecutive $s_1$'s, followed by $2^{2^2+T_2}$ consecutive $s_2$'s, followed by $2^{2^3+T_3}$ consecutive $s_3$'s, etc.. Then, for any $m \ge 1$, if $N$ is large enough, $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k \le N} e^{2\pi i x_k m} \approx \frac{1}{N_0}\sum_{t=0}^{N_0-1} f(\frac{t}{N_0})e^{2\pi i \frac{t}{N_0}m} \approx \int_0^1 f(x)e^{2\pi i xm}dx = \frac{-1}{3^m},$$ for some large $N_0$, the first approximation holding due to $f$ having mean $1$ (I'll leave details/quantifiers to you).

Comment: Thank you very much for this construction! Very interesting example.

Comment: ok @mathworker21 will definitely do, I think I got the general idea. But just a question on the exact construction of the sequence $x_k$: How can one deal with negative values of $f$ which I think occur? Then $j_t$ can get negative which should be the number that $t/N$ appears. Also how can we ensure that the block length is $M_N$ which is the denominator of the approximations?

Comment: @Schmelli for your second question, the definition of the length of the block is $M_N$. The definition of $M_N$ is just a common denominator of all of the rationals. your first question is a good one: now thinking about my answer, I don't think I use that $\hat{f}(0) = 1$; I think we just need $\hat{f}(m) = \frac{-1}{2^m}$ for $m \ge 1$, which should imply that $f$ is bounded I think (they imply $f$ is $C^\infty$ in a quantitative sense, and we also know $f$ is $L^2$), so we can just translate $f$ upwards to make it non-negative (which is fine, since I don't think we care about $\hat{f}(0)$).

Comment: Hi @mathworker21, thanks for the very quick reply yesterday. I think the upward translation of $f$ could work even though I think that would change the ratios between the $j_t$. Maybe its because I still struggle a bit with the role of the common denominator $M_N$. I understand its needed to make the $j_t$ comparable and to assign the "right portion" of $t/N$ in our approximation of $f$. But aren't the numbers $j_t$ entirely determining the length of the blocks $s_N$ in the above construction, so can we get to a block of length $M_N$ if for example the sum of $j_t$ are much higher?

Comment: @Schmelli sorry about that! For some reason, I had in my mind that $j_0+\dots+j_{N-1} = M_N$; I don't know why. See the updated answer. I think it addresses all your concerns.

Comment: Thanks @mathworker21, that was very useful!

Comment: @Schmelli I think boundedness of $f$ is obvious. By fourier inversion, $f(\theta) = \sum_m \frac{1}{2^m}\cos(2\pi m \theta)$ (or something like that).

Comment: Hi @mathworker21, just realized that the shift of $f$ could be a problem. If we skip of your initial condition $\hat{f}(0)=1$ we lose $1/N_0 \sum_{t=0}^{N_0-1} f(\frac{t}{N_0})= 1$ which I think is essential in the first approximation step of the last equation chain. Otherwise we could shift the bounded function very high up and that would imply a almost uniform distribution of the second sequence which I think wouldn't work.

Comment: @Schmelli thanks again, nice catch! It seems the limit would instead be $\frac{\int_0^1 f(x)e^{2\pi i mx}dx}{\int_0^1 f(x)dx}$, so we do indeed want $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$. However, I think my last comment might save the day. The real-valued function $f$ with $\hat{f}(0) = 1$ and $\hat{f}(m) = \frac{-1}{2^m}$ for $m \ge 1$ is $f(\theta) = 1-\sum_{m \ge 1}\frac{1}{2^m}\cos(2\pi m\theta)$ (please check this), which is non-negative (since $\sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{1}{2^m} = 1$). If you agree with all of this, then that's good; however, I'd feel a bit bad about how lucky we got...

Comment: Hi @mathworker21, thanks, unfortunately considering the Fourier coefficients for negative $m$ which we need in order to obtain a real-valued function I think we get a function that gets negative. Using $\exp(2\pi ix)+\exp(-2\pi ix)=2 \cos(2 \pi x)$ I arrived at $1-\cos(2\pi x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(4\pi x)-\frac{1}{4}\cos(6\pi x)...$ where $f(0)=-1$.

Comment: @Schmelli ah, I did consider the negative fourier coefficients, but forgot the factor of $2$. Ok, but it looks like we're close enough to getting lucky. In particular, if we redo the whole answer with $a_k = 1$ if $k$ is odd and $a_k = 3$ if $k$ is even, then I think the corresponding $f$ will be non-negative. It should be $1-\frac{2}{3}\cos(2\pi x)-\frac{2}{9}\cos(4\pi x)-\dots$, which is non-negative. Do you concur with all of this? If so, I'll retype the answer to fix everything.

Comment: Hi @mathworker21, yes that looks good. Just one more question: In the initial problem I also considered negative $m$ (all non-zero integers). Do you think a similar example could be constructed that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_k)^m e^{2 \pi i x_k m}=0$ holds also for negative $m$? In the above example I think we wouldn't have this due to the definition of the Fourier coefficients for negative values.Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Schmelli You would have to convince me of something first. In Weyl's criterion, negative $m$ is the same as positive $m$, due to conjugation. In the problem you're asking about now, negative $m$ is different from positive $m$, which makes the problem very unnatural to me and therefore uninteresting. Note that the construction of $f$ in my answer also explains why we want negative $m$ to be the same as positive $m$.

Comment: Hi @mathworker21, will try to convince you, but first thanks again for the great construction and the amount of time you looked into this, it made a lot much clearer for me. The problem I want to solve stems initially from analytic number theory and is concerned with the distribution of imaginary parts of nontrivial zeros of zeta functions. Essentially Landau proved that in the case of the Riemann zeta function for these zeros $\rho_k=\beta_k+ i\gamma_k$ the following holds: 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{\rho_k}=0$
for a free parameter $x>0$ but $x \neq 1$.

Comment: Part2 @mathworker21:  If we now set $x=e^{2 \pi m}$ and separate real and imaginary part we arrive at basically the problem I posted, since it is known that the real parts $\beta_k$ are bounded. But that holds also for negative $m$ where $ e^{2 \pi m}$ stays positive. 
Now it is shown that if the real parts are concentrated at one point (for example as assumed in the Riemann Hypothesis) then we can immediately apply Weyls criterion. I want to show that a similar assumption is necessary or that the Landau condition is enough to get uniform distribution

Comment: Part3 @mathworker21
which would be nice as a Landau type formula applies to other zeta functions as well.  I think, also given what I got from you that there is a counterexample but would be great to have an explicit one. 
I understand the point that negative $m$ need not to be looked at if a sequence is uniform distributed due to conjugation as you indicated. But looking the other way round couldn’t it still be possible that a condition like stated above which is valid for all $m \neq 0$ implies uniform distribution?

Comment: @Schmelli thanks! indeed interesting. However, I still see no reason why having the condition for negative $m$ will now yield a criterion for uniform distribution. But finding a counterexample seems much harder now. I'll think about it more.

Comment: Thanks @mathworker21, I think one reason that this condition could suffice is that it yields additional information for negative $m$, as we get $1/n \sum_{k \leq n} (a_k)^m \sin(2 \pi m x_k)$ and $1/n \sum_{k \leq n} 1/{(a_k)^m} \sin(2 \pi m x_k)$ tending to $0$ (analouge for $\cos$) which is in case of Weyl basically the same if we take constant weights $a_k=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Schmelli I thought I should let you know that I recently realized that the method used in the answer to construct a sequence with prescribed "fourier coefficients" is sharp. Namely, for $(c_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ (say), there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} e(kx_n) \to c_k$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the function $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_k e^{2\pi i kx}$ is non-negative for all $x \in \mathbb{T}$. The answer shows the "if" direction. To see the "only if" direction, let $\mu$ be a weak-$*$ limit of a subsequence of the measures

Comment: $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} \delta_{x_n}$. Then $\hat{\mu}(k) = c_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but also $\hat{f}(k) = c_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $f(x) := \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_ke^{2\pi i kx}$, so we must have $\mu = fdx$. If $f$ were negative at some point, then since it is continuous, it is negative in some open set $U$, which yields a contradiction: $0 > \int_U f \ge \liminf_k \frac{1}{N_k}\sum_{n \le N_k} \delta_{x_n}(U) \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks @mathworker21 for this hint. Do you know if there are necessary and sufficient conditions on the Fourier coefficients $c_k$ such that $f$ is non-negative? I am not an expert on Fourier analysis, but from what I read this is not easy to determine.

Comment: @Schmelli I don't think there's a nice criterion.